# Python Multiprocessing Being Extremely Slow

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyomo

I'm trying to run an optimization model in pyomo/python multiple times in a loop with only one changing parameter which is c_param and c_param takes values of 1 to 170. I'm also trying to do this using parallel computing using multiprocessing module with 6 processors. However, I think I have some error in the way I set this up because the multiprocessing method is slower than no multiprocessing. So I have:

```
    import multiprocessing as mp

    # Global parameters defined here.
    S = list(range(170))
    def my_model(c_param):
        # My pyomo model here
        # Print model results to csv

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        c_param= [i + 1 for i in S]

        pool = mp.Pool(6)
        pool.map(my_model, S)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

I expect to have 170 csv files printed out. I can achieve this just fine with a normal loop but it takes about 40 hours to do so. I'm hoping to accelerate this to 6-7 hours using 6 processors but somehow this takes even longer. Did I do something wrong there that would slow down the process? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have enough memory to handle 6 processes at once without swapping?

Comment: I do. I run this on a university owned supercomputing system

Comment: Without seeing what my_model does it is hard to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you selecting the correct number of cores in your job to the cluster? I ask since the number of cores available to the job by default may be what's at fault for the dramatic slowdown, which can occur when the pool size is larger than the number of available cores.

Comment: you might want to profile your code https://github.com/benfred/py-spy

Comment: @VikashB the model is quite long and large so I didnt include it here. But it is a mixed integer linear programming problem of over 8 million variables.

Comment: @jrd1 yes I do. the cluster allows 20 cores on one node and total of 1000 GB memory so I requested 6 cores with 160GB memory each, so it's close to maxed out computing budget but its still within it.

Comment: @TaylorCochran Thank you. I'll take a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

If the model function contains many and/or deeply nested objects it may take longer because objects need to be pickled/serialized before being sent to other processes. It is hard to tell without knowing what is in the model function however.

Comment: The model is quite large but I dont think it has many nested objects. It is a mixed integer linear programming with over 8 million variables. I tried to run it without multiprocessing and it takes about 13 minutes to finish one iteration (one result file printed out). With multiprocessing, it takes almost 3 hours before I see one result file got printed out.